# onclick issue in firefox

Tags: firefox, cross-browser

Why this onclick event doesn't fire in Firefox, while it fires in IE ? What is the equivalent working construction for Firefox ?

```
<a href="" onclick="invoke(this); return false;">link</a>
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction should behave identically in Firefox and IE. Your problem is probably in the `invoke()` function.

Try using Firefox's JavaScript console to find the detailed error message.

Comment: Indeed, I had a problem in the invoke() function. I was getting some text needed for further steps, but the text was undefined. I've changed the way of getting the text from DOM element from obj.innerText (good for IE but not for Firefox) to $(obj).text() and it works.

Answer (score 0):

i try your link in firefox this work properly check your invoke method may be error in this pass parameters ininvoke method then your problem solved.